# How to use Catmull-Rom interpolation in D3 v3?

Tags: d3.js

D3 v4+ comes with `curveCatmullRom` interpolation mode, but I'm currently stuck with D3 v3, which doesn't seem to have that

I see there's a "https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/src/curve/catmullRom.js" in d3-shapes, would that be able to be reappropriated as an interpolation factory here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out -

```
import { line, curveCatmullRom } from 'd3-shape';

const catmulRomInterpolation = (points) =>
  line()
    .curve(curveCatmullRom)(points)
    .replace(/^M/, '');

d3.svg.line().interpolate(catmulRomInterpolation)
```